# How can we express the comma when we speak?

Tags: grammar, pronunciation

There are two sentences that have slightly different meaning.

1. I have three daughters who became nurses.
2. I have three daughters, who became nurses.

But when we speak the two sentences, How can we speak the two sentences differently? (How can we express the comma when we speak?)

Could you tell me the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a marked tonal difference between the sentences.

In the first

```
|-rise--|---peak----|---------fall-----|            
I have three daughters who became nurses.

|-rise--|---peak-----||low--rise-----fall|
I have three daughters, who became nurses.
```

There are two intonation groups in the second sentence but only one in the first. Even without a pause, the pattern of intonation gives clues to the structure, and the punctuation reflects that.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence with the comma has a very short pause where the comma goes:

> I have three daughters who became nurses.
>
> I have three daughters *(very short pause)* who became nurses.

In the first sentence, you're saying that you have "three daughters who became nurses," possibly implying you have more daughters who did not become nurses.

In the second sentence, you're saying that you have three daughters, all of whom became nurses.

You can see the change in emphasis based on where the pause goes in the sentence. By saying "I have three daughters" and pausing slightly, you're emphasizing that you have three daughters, then you go on to describe your three daughters after the pause.

Comment: I don’t think the comma belongs in the sentence. If I was quoting someone who had inserted a pause, and I wanted to convey that pause, I might use a dash instead: _I have three daughters – who became nurses_.

Comment: @J.R. Fair point.